# What happens exactly in the i/o of json files?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I struggled with the following for a couple of hours yesterday.  I figured out a workaround, but I'd like to understand a little more of what's going on in the background and, ideally, I'd like to remove the intermediate file from my code just for the sake of elegance.  I'm using python, by the way and files_df starts off as a pandas dataframe.

Can you help me understand why the following code gives me an error.

```
    files_json = files_df.to_json(orient='records')

    for file_json in files_json:
        print(file_json) #do stuff
```

But this code works?

```
    files_json = files_df.to_json(orient='records')
    with open('export_json.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(files_json)

    with open('export_json.json') as data:
        files_json = json.load(data)

    for file_json in files_json:
        print(file_json) #do stuff
```

Obviously, the export/import is converting the data somehow into a usable format.  I would like to understand that a little better and know if there is some option within the pandas files_df.to_json command to perform the same conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json.load is the opposite of json.dump, but you export from pandas data frames into file and than import again with standard library into some sort of python structure.
Try **files_df.to_dict**

Comment: Yup.  That did it.  I guess I just got hung up on the fact that the example that I was trying to follow used json format, so I exported to json.  Thank you!